# InstallShield - Setting up registry entries under HKCU

Tags: registry, installshield-le

I am using "InstallShield 2013 Limited Edition for Visual Studio".

I would like to add a registry entry under HKEY_CURRENT_USER. In my installshield project, I drag and drop the entries from "Source computer's Registry view" to "Destination computer Registry view". I built the project and created the setup.exe file.

When I tried to install the setup.exe in my test machine, the above registry entries are only installed to the person who installed the setup not to every users.

Kindly help me resolving the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not find any other option to resolve my issue. There were few suggestion to use "Active Setup" method. But it is not helping to update changes made on registry entries/values on later releases.

The best way I found is creating a script to import a .reg file during Windows startup. Now I have more control on what HKCU entries should have.

thank you all for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

When using the HKEY_CURRENT_USER as your place of registration key. It will result for current user installation.
When using the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE every user on that machine wil get the key.

Comment: I know that. What I am trying to do is adding a key in Current_user should reflect on every user's HKCU ...

Comment: Did you look at [Link-AllUsers](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield18helplib/mergedProjects/installshield18langref/ALLUSERS.htm)